# Invalid Patent Since Concept is Already in Public Domain?

Tags: us20090013028

Patent us20090013028

This concept has already been developed by MIT in 1996 per The Filament Chip: http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/Filament/index.html

The patent should be invalidated since the concept is in the public domain.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

This is an **application** not an issued patent. Application numbers start with something that looks like a year while US patents are numbered sequentially and now are in the 8 millions. The full history and status of published application from mid 2003 on are available to public access on the site [USPTO Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). It shows that the application has been rejected multiple times and is currently waiting for the appeals board to rule on it. I also see that the claims have been amended since it was published.

I haven't read the file wrapper to see what has been cited against it but I agree with you that this seems old. In 2008 PC Magazine had an article on the [10 greats hacks of all time](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2330368,00.asp) that covered several coke machines on the Internet dating from 1991.